# How to handle special characters when converting from HTML to DocX

Tags: java, html, docx, docx4j

I have a application that converts html files to DocX using DocX4J.
I´m having problems with special characters like ç,á,é,í,ã,etc.
My text font in the html files is Arial but when I convert them to DocX the special characters mentioned before are set to calibri font. So, in the same word (e.g Cláudio), I have "Cl" written in Arial font, "á" character in Calibri font and "udio" in Arial font.

I saw that maybe I have to set font property in w:r but I´m having difficulty to see how to do it to all runs of my text been converted. Also, I can´t see how to do it in my conversion code, that is listed below (with a sample html).

Any tip or suggestion about how to do this conversion and handle those special characters would be really great.

Cheers.

```
public WordprocessingMLPackage export(String xhtml) {

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
try {
    wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    XHTMLImporter importer = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
    List<Object> content = importer.convert(xhtml,null);
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(content);
}
catch (Docx4JException e) {
    // ...
}
return wordMLPackage;
}
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    page-break-before: always;
}

p, h1 {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
    line-height: 150%;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 130%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RESUMO<br /></h1>
<p>
    <span>Um resumo para o relatório.</span><br />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285650/docx4j-chaging-language-settings-for-docdefaultstyle-proper-applying-customor

Comment: See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/XHTMLImporterImpl.java lines 272 to 306; add a mapping Arial to the font you want to use in Word (ie check its called Arial there).

Comment: It worked @JasonPlutext! Thanks!
I posted the final code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the tip given by JasonPlutext, I found an example of how to map a font to the XHTMLImporter at the DocX4J forum (http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/docx-to-html-and-back-to-docx-t1913.html).

Now my code is working!
See the final version below.

---

```
public WordprocessingMLPackage export(String xhtml) {

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
try {
    RFonts arialRFonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
    arialRFonts.setAscii("Arial");
    arialRFonts.setHAnsi("Arial");
    XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping("Arial", arialRFonts);

    wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    XHTMLImporter importer = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
    List<Object> content = importer.convert(xhtml,null);
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(content);
}
catch (Docx4JException e) {
    // ...
}
return wordMLPackage;
}
```